# Empirical mean excess plot of (μ, e(μ))

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, random, simulation

Say I generated n random variates from the standard cauchy distribution. I want to construct the empirical mean excess plot of (μ, e(μ)) , where
e(μ)={Σ(xi-μ) **I* {xi>=μ}}/Nμ . Nμ is the number of values xi that exceed the μ and the summation part is all xi that exceed the μ(the threshold value), i=1,...,n. Could someone know how to plot this? Thanks!

Comment: What does the plus sign in your summation mean? What is $\mu$ here? Can you share a link to a definition?

Comment: @MarcoB, [link](https://www.casact.org/community/affiliates/cae/1014/4_Pena_CAE_EVT.pdf), please refer to the link on page 17. I revised the formula and μ is  a threshold value.

Comment: Leslie, thank you for the details. Is the approach in my answer satisfactory then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spit-balling a little here, based on my best understanding of your definition:

```
n = 500;
variates = RandomVariate[CauchyDistribution[], n];

ClearAll[meanExcess]
meanExcess[data_, mu_] := 
 Total[#]/Length[#]& @ Cases[data, x_?(# > mu &) :> x - mu]

Plot[meanExcess[variates, mu], {mu, 0, 10}]
```

[image: proposed plot]

Comment: (`Total[#]/Length[#] &` is just `Mean`, of course.)

Comment: @J.M. Very true! I was so caught up in reproducing the formula that I didn't stop to think about it :-)

Answer (score 5):

Three additional ways to implement empirical mean excess using

1. [`TruncatedDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TruncatedDistribution.html) + [`EmpiricalDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html)
2. [`UnitStep`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep.html) + [`Pick`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html)
3. [`Clip`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip.html) + [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html)

```
ClearAll[eme1, eme2, eme3]

eme1[data_, μ_] := Mean @ TruncatedDistribution[{μ, ∞}, EmpiricalDistribution @ data]

eme2[data_, μ_] := Mean @ Pick[data, UnitStep[data - μ], 1]

eme3[data_, μ_] := Mean @ DeleteCases[Null] @ Clip[data, {μ, ∞}, {Null, ∞}]
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1]
rv = RandomVariate[CauchyDistribution[], 100];
```

Verify that all three methods give the same result when the threshold parameter is within the sample range:

```
Max @ Chop[{Norm[eme1[rv, #] - eme2[rv, #]], 
     Norm[eme1[rv, #] - eme3[rv, #]], 
     Norm[eme2[rv, #] - eme3[rv, #]]} & /@ RandomReal[MinMax[rv], 500]]
```

> ```
>  0
> ```

```
Plot[{eme1[rv, x], eme2[rv, x], eme3[rv, x]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[7], Red], 
   Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3], Blue], Directive[Thin, Green]}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, PlotLegends -> {"eme1", "eme2", "eme3"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following an example, I tried to make it this way:

```
    n = 100000;
SeedRandom[123456];
x = RandomVariate[CauchyDistribution[0, 1], n];
x = Sort[x, Greater];
meanExcess =Table[{x[[k + 1]], Mean[x[[1 ;; k]] - x[[k + 1]]]}, {k, 1, 99999}];
ListPlot[meanExcess, AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 18, Italic, Bold] &) /@ {"x[[k+1]]", 
"meanExcess"}, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]